# How to invoke the super constructor in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, constructor, superclass

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("world")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
       print("hello")

B()  # output: hello
```

In all other languages I've worked with the super constructor is invoked implicitly. How does one invoke it in Python? I would expect `super(self)` but this doesn't work.

Comment: you should emphasize that an answer that doesn't use the Derived Class name is what you want. e.g. (pseudocode): `super().__init__(args...)`

Comment: you should be accepting Aidan Gomez's answer. It would save us a lot of time, since it has an answer in both python 2 and 3.

Comment: Python 2 is no longer officially supported. Also his answer came 5 years later.

Comment: @Mike I think there's still value in an answer that lists the Python 2 way, because there's a lot of old Python 2 code floating around out there, and some of the people who wind up at this question probably won't otherwise know how to make sense of it. (And despite it being EOL, many people _do_ still write code in Python 2, either because they don't know better or because some organizational requirement has forced it on them.)

Comment: I have changed the accepted answer to @Aiden Gomez's answer. Though Ignacio was correct, @Aidan's was the most appropriate as of today given Python 3's changes to `super()`

Answer (score 454, accepted):

In line with the other answers, there are multiple ways to call super class methods (including the constructor), however in Python 3 the process has been simplified:

#### Python 3

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("world")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
        super().__init__()
```

#### Python 2

In Python 2, you have to call the slightly more verbose version `super(<containing classname>, self)`, which is equivalent to `super()`as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#super).

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "world"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "hello"
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 378):

`super()` returns a parent-like object *in new-style classes*:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("world")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
        super(B, self).__init__()

B()
```

Comment: just of curiosity why does `super(B,self)` require both B and self to be mentioned? isn't this redundant? shouldn't self contain a reference to B already?

Comment: No, because `self` might actually be an instance of `C`, a child of `B`.

Comment: What if `B(A, AA)`? I see that `super(B,self)` returns `A`, but then how do you get `AA`?

Comment: @iuliux: In that case, if `self` is an instance of `B`, then `super(B, self).__init__()` calls the method defined in `A` and `super(A, self).__init__()` calls the method defined in `AA`. If you're writing classes that might be multiply inherited from, you should always include a call to the `super` constructor, but which code that actually invokes depends on the inheritance decisions of your subclasses. See http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/ for more details.

Comment: Addition to the post: "new-style classes" means python3.

Comment: @Luc not quite. It's a term used in Python 2. [They were introduced in Python 2.2.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) You might be referring to the fact that they're the only available type of class in Python 3?

Comment: @DanGetz I don't really know. All I observed was that my code (using `super(B,self).__init__(args)`) didn't work using python 2.7.6, but it does work using python 3.4.0.

Comment: @Luc: That's because the class was declared incorrectly. See my answer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ah I see, there was no 'object' argument in A's constructor. My bad!

Comment: With respect to the [documentation of `super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), you should be able to write `super().__init__()` wothout arguments.

Comment: @JojOatXGME: In 3.x, yes. 2.x still needs the arguments.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ok. Maybe you should mention that you are using python 2.x in your answer? I'm relative new to python and I think it is a little bit confusing that many sites do not write whether they are using python 2 or 3.?

Comment: The original post was written six years ago; python 3 was barely a thing at that point.

Comment: What is the rationale behind passing B (child Class) and self (child like object) to the super method? Ex.: super(B, self).__init__().

Comment: @router: Python 2.x didn't use introspection in `super` to figure out what the relevant class and object were, so you had to pass them.

Comment: Why is the super function called last (I switching the order and python just ignored the code after the super_init, why is that?)

Comment: @borgr: Because we want "hello" to print before "world". If this isn't an issue in your code then call it whenever appropriate.

Comment: Finaly: what will the above code output? That should be added to the answer.

Comment: your answer is the most viewed. Wouldn't it be useful to extend your answer to explain what is the best practice for python 3? I believe it's: don't use derived class name do this in python 3 (pseudocode): `super().__init__(args...)`

Answer (score 53):

With Python 2.x old-style classes it would be this:

```
class A: 
 def __init__(self): 
   print "world" 

class B(A): 
 def __init__(self): 
   print "hello" 
   A.__init__(self)
```

Comment: @kdbanman: This will work with new-style classes, but one of the reasons to use new-style classes is to not have to do it this way. You can use `super` and not have to directly name the class you're inheriting from.

Comment: @Gabe That's one of the least important reasons to use `super`.

Answer (score 37):

One way is to call A's constructor and pass `self` as an argument, like so:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        print "hello"
```

The advantage of this style is that it's very clear.  It call A's initialiser.  The downside is that it doesn't handle diamond-shaped inheritance very well, since you may end up calling the shared base class's initialiser twice.

Another way is to use super(), as others have shown.  For single-inheritance, it does basically the same thing as letting you call the parent's initialiser.

However, super() is quite a bit more complicated under-the-hood and can sometimes be counter-intuitive in multiple inheritance situations.  On the plus side, super() can be used to handle diamond-shaped inheritance.  If you want to know the nitty-gritty of what super() does, the best explanation I've found for how super() works is [here](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) (though I'm not necessarily endorsing that article's opinions).

Comment: Is there any need to call A's constructor like this when it doesn't take any variable(ignoring self) as an argument? I mean the code works fine without `A.__init__(self)` line.

Comment: @RedFloyd It depends on what `A.__init__` actually does. It may initialize various internal attributes in a constant fashion (`self.stuff = []`, e.g.), which may cause your instance of `B` to not behave correctly if you don't call `A.__init__`.

Answer (score 20):

Just to add an example with parameters:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        A.__init__(self, x, y)
```

Given a derived class B that requires the variables x, y, z to be defined, and a superclass A that requires x, y to be defined, you can call the static method **init** of the superclass A with a reference to the current subclass instance (self) and then the list of expected arguments.

Comment: this is a more correct answer as the class that renders as super() can change... this makes it clear which constructor you want to call

Answer (score 17):

**Short Answer**

```
super(DerivedClass, self).__init__()
```

**Long Answer**

*What does `super()` do?*

It takes specified class name, finds its base classes (Python allows multiple inheritance) and looks for the method (`__init__` in this case) in each of them from left to right. As soon as it finds method available, it will call it and end the search.

*How do I call init of all base classes?*

Above works if you have only one base class. But Python does allow multiple inheritance and you might want to make sure all base classes are initialized properly. To do that, you should have each base class call init:

```
class Base1:
  def __init__(self):
    super(Base1, self).__init__()

class Base2:
  def __init__(self):
    super(Base2, self).__init__()

class Derived(Base1, Base2):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Derived, self).__init__()
```

*What if I forget to call init for super?*

The constructor (`__new__`) gets invoked in a chain (like in C++ and Java). Once the instance is created, only that instance's initialiser (`__init__`) is called, without any implicit chain to its superclass.

Comment: `__new__` isn't chained, either. If all three classes in your example defined `__new__`, but didn't use `super().__new__()`, then `Derived()` would call `Derived.__new__` but not `Base1.__new__` or `Base2.__new__`. A `__new__` that doesn't call its parent's `__new__` is almost useless, though, because ultimately `object.__new__` is the only thing that truly creates a new instance of anything.

Comment: PyLint recommends using Python 3 style super() without arguments

Answer (score -3):

I use the following formula that extends previous answers:

```
class A(object):
 def __init__(self):
   print "world"

class B(A):
 def __init__(self):
   print "hello"
   super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

B()
```

This way you don't have to repeat the name of the class in the call to *super*. It can come handy if you are coding a large number of classes, and want to make your code in the initialiser methods independent of the class name.

Comment: But you will get infinitive recursion if decide to extend `B` with `C`, and `self.__class__` points to `C(B)` instead of `B(A)`, so `super(self.__class__, self)` points back to `B` instead of `A`.

Comment: This will lead to infinite recursion errors when you subclass `B`. Do **not** use `self.__class__` or `type(self)`, either pass in an explicit class (`B` here) or, in Python 3, use `super()` without arguments.