# How do I return a 401 Unauthorized in Django?

Tags: python, django

Instead of doing this:

```
res = HttpResponse("Unauthorized")
res.status_code = 401
return res
```

Is there a way to do it without typing it every time?

Comment: [Kindly use `Unauthenticated`, instead of `Unauthorized` for the status code of 401.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937030/6282576)

Answer (score 170):

I know this is an old one, but it's the top Google result for "django 401", so I thought I'd point this out...

Assuming you've already imported `django.http.HttpResponse`, you can do it in a single line:

```
return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
```

The `'Unauthorized'` string is optional. Easy.

Comment: This is passable and I upvoted it; however - for a similar scenario I would consider using error 403 (Forbidden) instead - for that there is a ready mechanism: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view - just define `handler403` in root `urls.py`, and then `raise django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied`.

Comment: @TomaszGandor Yep, or `return HttpResponseForbidden` works for 403s too (raising an exception as you’ve suggested it often more convenient). 401 and 403 aren’t quite the same though, although some argue over the exact difference.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the 401 response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field. So, it's simpler to use 403. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @SimonSteinberger Very true, but there isn’t a standard `WWW-Authenticate` header that any systems will recognise for most auth systems today, so unless you’re using Basic Auth I’d argue this is a pragmatic case to violate the spec.

IMO 403 has a separate purpose (i.e. you’ve authenticated but you’re not allowed to access this [403] vs you haven’t authenticated yet [401])

Comment: gz for the gold medal @Stu Cox

Comment: I can't think of a use case of 401 without an API, so if anyone has an idea.. And API framework like drf usually include a 401: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/

Comment: @Jean-XavierRaynaud Why? Because you'd normally redirect to a login page rather than returing a 401?
I can't even remember what my use case was for returning a 401 when I wrote this answer! It might have been hand-rolling an API, or some edge case we didn't want to redirect to login for some reason.

Comment: Does anyone know why django.http.response doesn't have a class for this? It has for other status codes.

Comment: To answer above questions, 403 is for failed authorization, 401 is for failed authentication per w3 spec.  Two very different things.

Answer (score 12):

```
class HttpResponseUnauthorized(HttpResponse):
    status_code = 401

...
return HttpResponseUnauthorized()
```

Normally, you should set the instance in `__init__` or you end up with class variables that are shared between all instances. However, Django does this for you already:

```
class HttpResponse(object):
    """A basic HTTP response, with content and dictionary-accessed headers."""

    status_code = 200

    def __init__(self, content='', mimetype=None, status=None,
            content_type=None):
        # snip...
        if status:
            self.status_code = status
```

([see the Django code in context](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.3/django/http/__init__.py#L566))

Answer (score 12):

**Inheritance solution**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class Http401(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('401 Unauthorized', status=401)
```

in a `util.py` to replace multiple calls to:

```
return HttpResponse('401 Unauthorized', status=401)
```

with just:

```
return Http401()
```

Interestingly there are other named responses in 1.9.6 https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.6/django/http/response.py#L443 but not 401.

Comment: I like this response.  But the line of  `__init__(self):` should change like this   `super(Http401, self).__init__(message, status=401)`

Comment: @Hobaak In Python 3 we can write just `super().__init__`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33191175/895245 . A `message` could be added, but if you're not doing APIs, just HTTP browser endpoints, it is not very necessary.

Comment: OK.  The solution threw me an error in 1.8.6 Django with 2.7 Python.  My suggestion helped go away the issue. Maybe it works with Python 3.  I like this solution most out of these answers nevertheless.

Comment: You can add to the end of the `__init__`: `self['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'FormBased'` if you want to meet the requirements to include that header when responding with a 401.

Answer (score 9):

```
class HttpResponseUnauthorized(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self):
        self.status_code = 401

...
return HttpResponseUnauthorized()
```

Comment: You don't need to put it in the `__init__` method, just set the attribute in the class definition.

Comment: @Matthew: I generally don't do that.  It makes it too easy to fall into the unintentionally-shared-object trap, and it's unclear to put some initialization in the class body and some in `__init__`.

Comment: This returns the following error:

`'HttpResponseUnauthorized' object has no attribute '_headers'`

Comment: from looking at django.http.__init__.py adding it in the class definition seems to be the preferred way to do it, should call HttpRepsonses constructor via super if you wish to do it in __init__

Comment: throws object has no attribute '_headers'

Answer (score 3):

Write a view decorator that checks the appropriate HTTP headers and returns the appropriate response (there is no [built-in type](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses) for response code 401).