# Django login_required decorator with view based behavior

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a url structure in in Django like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('me/', profile_view, name='my_profile'),
    path('<uuid:account_id>/', profile_view, name='user_profile')
]
```

and my profile_view is like this:

```
@login_required
def profile_view(request, account_id=None):
    # ...
```

I want to use login required decorator to only require login if `account_id = None`? So, if someone goes to `/accounts/me` URL, the system must require authenticated user. Otherwise, the page should be accessible.

Comment: The `@login_required` decorator will not help you with this. You should add a manual test to the view function itself.

Comment: Then, after the test, do I just redirect or do I throw an exception and the auth system redirects properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356842/how-do-i-return-a-401-unauthorized-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the `login_required` decorator in the URL config:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('me/', login_required(profile_view), name='my_profile'),
    path('<uuid:account_id>/', profile_view, name='user_profile')
]
```

Then remove `login_required` from the `profile_view` itself.