# Redirecting in Django with a specific status code

Tags: python, django, redirect

If a user tries to access a page, I want him to be redirected to the login page, but with a status code 401 (unauthorized). Like this:

```
if not 'logged_user' in request.session:
    return redirect('mqr_admin:login', status=401)
```

But the `redirect()` function doesn't have the `status` param as the function `render()` has. What should I do?

Comment: you can either pass it to the function that is called attached to the endpoint, or (I wouldn't) pass it as a url parameter, as in mqr_admin:login?status=401

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356842/how-do-i-return-a-401-unauthorized-in-django

Comment: If your real goal is to redirect the user to a login page, why do you care what the response code is?

Comment: @JohnGordon I was just wondering if that was a real thing I could do.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `HttpResponse`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def yourView(request):    
    return HttpResponse('401 Unauthorized', status=401)
```

The solution was found here: [How do I return a 401 Unauthorized in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356842/how-do-i-return-a-401-unauthorized-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a thing you can do.

In HTTP, redirects are codes 3xx, mainly 301 and 302. That is how the browser knows to do a redirect at all.

If you return a 4xx status code, the browser will treat it as an error, not a redirect.