# Class attribute overriding: keep parent class changes

Tags: python

I want two class. Class A with a default class attribute and class B (child class) who override this class attribute. But if A class attribute definition is changed by developper, i don't want to write again B class attribute.

Exemple: With simple override:

```
class Animal:
    actions = {}

class Dog(Animal):
    actions = {'bite': 1}
```

If a day, `Animal` is modified like this:

```
class Animal:
    actions = {'bleed': 1}
```

Dog class have to be rewrited. So i do that to prevent parent class update:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...   d = {}
...   @classmethod
...   def c(cls):
...     print(cls.d)
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   d = A.d.copy()
...   d.update({0: 1})
... 
>>> B.c()
{0: 1}
>>> A.c()
{}
```

Is this a good way to do it? Or is there a more "python way" to do it?

Comment: you never change A.d

Comment: What's the meaning of overloading a class attribute, anyway?

Comment: I rewrite question considering yours.

Comment: You might find this link on evoking parent classes constructors in python useful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/python-invoke-super-constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Attribute copying in class method

By using `copy` you are ensuring `A`'s `d`, no matter what/who defines it, will be the starting point before `B` extends it.

```
class A:
    d = {}
    @classmethod
    def c(cls):
        print (cls.d)

class B(A):
    d = A.d.copy()
    d.update({0:1})

B.c()
A.c()
```

output

```
{0: 1}
{}
```

developer changes `A` at a later time, `B` gets `A` without touching `B`'s definition.

```
class A:
    d = {2:3}
    @classmethod
    def c(cls):
        print (cls.d)

class B(A):
    d = A.d.copy()
    d.update({0:1})

B.c()
A.c()
```

output

```
{0: 1, 2: 3}
{2: 3}
```

*Warning:* If `d` contains other objects inside it, you may want to use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#module-copy), otherwise only the first "level" will be copied, all others objects will be references to the original (this caused me *a lot* of grief once, before I knew about it!).

#### Inheriting in instance method

The dictionary copying is pythonic in the sense that it is clear that `B` gets `A` and extends it, but since you will probably be creating instances in your use case (of say `Dog`), these classes might be missing the concept of a [class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609238/2087463) by using the `__init__` method. This will allow you to have multiple `B`s with potentially unique `d`s.

Here is an example of class definitions with an instance in mind

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}
    def c(self):
        print (self.d)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        self.d.update({0:1})

# create instances of each class
a = A()
b1 = B() 
b2 = B()  

# call each instance's c method
b1.c()
b2.c()
a.c()

# you can even update on the fly without affecting the other!
a.d.update({2:3})
b1.d.update({4:5})
b2.d.update({7:8})
b1.c()
b2.c()
a.c()
```

output

```
{0: 1}
{0: 1}
{}
{0: 1, 4: 5}
{0: 1, 7: 8}
{2: 3}
```