# python 2.7 - how to call parent class constructor

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have base class like below

```
class FileUtil:
    def __init__(self):
        self.outFileDir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'processed')
        if not os.path.exists(outFileDir):
            os.makedirs(outFileDir)
    ## other methods of the class
```

and I am extending this class as below:

```
class Myfile(FileUtil):
    def __init__(self, extension):
        super(Myfile, self).__init__()
        self.extension = 'text'
    ## other methods of class
```

But i am getting below error?

```
super(Myfile, self).__init__()
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

I gone through many documents and found that there are different sytex of calling super() in 2.x and 3.x. I tried both ways but getting error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, invoke super constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/python-invoke-super-constructor)

Comment: i don't see any troubles with your code

Comment: I am using this code in Django..Although I can understand there is nothing Django specific but still asking if there is something i am missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 options

old style class, you should call the super constructor directly.

```
class FileUtil():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Myfile(FileUtil):
    def __init__(self, extension):
        FileUtil.__init__(self)
```

new style class, inherit from object in your base class and your current call to super will be processed correctly.

```
class FileUtil(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Myfile(FileUtil):
    def __init__(self, extension):
        super(Myfile, self).__init__()
```

Comment: They differ as described. The first one calls the super constructor differently and the second one inherits from `object`.

Comment: Second example is what OP's using and having issues. So it's not an answer to OP's question

Comment: @minitoto in his code `class FileUtil:` in my code `class FileUtil(object):`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create the `FileUtil` class using the `super()` function as well:

```
class FileUtil(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FileUtil, self).__init__()
        ...
```