# Is it possible to initialize a Python subclass by calling a function that returns an instance of its superclass?

Tags: python, class, numpy, initialization

I'm trying to create a class that inherits `numpy.ndarray`, but I want to initialize it using a function that returns an `ndarray`. Specifically I want to generate an `ndarray` from a CSV file using the convenient `numpy.genfromtxt()` function. For example (I'm aware that this code does not do what I want it to):

```
class MyClass(numpy.ndarray):
    def __init__(self, other_parameter):
        self = numpy.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',')
        self.other_param = other_parameter
```

The point is that I want to extend `ndarray` a little bit by adding other features/attributes without losing the interface to `ndarray`. I know I can cobble together attributes in a class with one being the `ndarray`. Is extending it possible using a constructor (within my class definition `__init__()`) that isn't `super().__init__()`?

I've found answers to this type of thing for several other languages, but not Python. I've wanted to use similar init functions before, and have never found how to do this.

Comment: What you're looking for is calling `super()` - take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/how-to-invoke-the-super-constructor)

Comment: @RobertSeaman: `super()` will not be helpful, because `numpy.genfromtxt` isn't the `numpy.ndarray` constructor method. `numpy.genfromtxt` returns a new array rather than initializing an uninitialized one.

Comment: Subclassing from `numpy.ndarray` is non-trivial. See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#implications-for-subclassing).

Comment: The best you can do is copying the array returned by `genfromtxt`; you can't have `genfromtxt` initialize your `MyClass` object directly.

Comment: Regardless, if this is all you want inheritance seems like overkill.

Comment: @user2357112 hmm, just curious, but couldn't the array returned form `genfromtxt` act as the underyling `buffer` for the `__new__` array?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: True, you could take a view over it instead of copying. You can't force the `genfromtxt` return value into being a `MyClass` instance, but you can reuse its buffer.

Comment: @user2357112 sounds like a lot of dark magic just to wrap `genfromtext` in a constructor...

Comment: Why subclass at all? Why not just have the array be an attribute of MyClass and then initialize it however you want? What are you gaining from the inheritance?

Comment: @juanpa: Thanks! That looks very helpful. Maybe it is overkill.
So far I've handled such situations by calling the constructor and making that super-class instance an attribute of my class, but that is clunkier than I hoped for. I am trying to make a new class that acts just like `ndarray` with some extra features, which is the point of inheritance in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Credit for this answer belongs mostly to [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) for the comment above. The answer is [this section of the link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) provided. The rest of the information from that [whole doc page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) is helpful to understand it fully.

The short answer is that one uses the `__new__()` constructor (standard Python that I didn't know about yet) and "view casting", which is special `ndarray` functionality, within the custom class definition.