# Python TypeError inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, typeerror, parent

First, sorry if the question seems to be similar to some previously raised issues; but they didn't help me.I'm trying to use a parent class within a child one. Both classes receive the same input as below:

The parent (PA.py):

```
class The_Parent():
    def __init__(self,in1=None,in2=None,in3=None):
#
# and the rest of codes ...
```

And the child (CH.py):

```
class The_Child(The_Parent)
    def __init__(self,in1,in2,in3):
       The_Parent.__init__(self,in1,in2,in3)
#
#
# the rest of code ...
```

And now, the main function:

```
# import requirements and assigning the variables (in1, in2, and in3)
# 
obj = CH.The_Child(in1,in2,in3)
#
#
```

And the error I got:

```
TypeError: The_Child() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Just a point, both child and parent should receive the same variables...

Comment: You have either a typo or multiple definitions.

Comment: This code does not give the behaviour you claim. Please post a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: Not related but `The_Parent.__init__(self, in1, in2, in3)` is just wrong (You will lose multiple inheritance benefits). Use `super(The_Child, self).__init__(in1, in2, in3)`

Comment: First thanks, unfortunately, I'm getting the same error using the mentioned super structure.

Comment: @ir0098 I just said it was not related. By the way, `class The_Parent():` will yield unexpected behavior. Use `class The_Parent(object):` instead.

Comment: you can write dummy code and post it, then only it would be more feasible to solve your issue.

Comment: # The begining of the Parent class:
  
  if None in (in1,in2,in3):
   sys.exit()
  self.in1 = in1        
  self.in2 = in2
  self.in3 = in3

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Also, specify which version of Python you are using.

Comment: @MatiasCicero again the same error with class The_Parent(object):

Comment: @Sumit all right guys,thanks.@khelwood

Comment: @ir0098 Please note that my code suggestions **are not the solution to your problem**. You are having a different kind of issue and I'm just posting unrelated comments on how you can better improve your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to call Parent constructor, you can call it using "super" keyword of Python, for more reference you can follow following link: [How to invoke the super constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/how-to-invoke-the-super-constructor])

Comment: thanks guy, just managed to solve the problem using Super structure as:         super(The_Parent,self).__init__(in1,in2,in3)