# Is it necessary to call super().__init__() explicitly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, constructor

I came from Java where we can avoid calling super class zero-argument constructor. The call to it is generated implicitly by the compiler.

I read [this post about super()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2399307/8990329) and now in question about is it really necessary to do something like this explicitly:

```
class A(object):
 def __init__(self):
   print("world")

class B(A):
 def __init__(self):
   print("hello")
   super().__init__() #Do we get some Undefined Behavior if we do not call it explicitly?
```

Comment: Does "world" get printed if you omit it?

Comment: @Sayse The question is not about behavior of a particular python implementation. It is about legitimacy in general.

Comment: Yes, but the answer should become clear whether it prints or not

Comment: @Sayse It does! So generally it can be avoided... Which is not clear why they mentioned it explcitly

Comment: World does not get printed.. [example](https://ideone.com/O60xQl)

Comment: @Sayse So we left superclass uninitialized. Is it UB?

Comment: Omitting super init is not UB, just like omitting any other calls. Objects are well defined before init.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you override the `__init__` method of the superclass, then the `__init__` method of the subclass needs to explicitly call it if that is the intended behavior, yes.

Your mental model of `__init__` is incorrect; it is not the constructor method, it is a hook which the constructor method calls to let you customize object initialization easily. (The actual constructor is called `__new__` but you don't need to know this, and will probably never need to interact with it directly, let alone change it.)