# Object of a parentclass inside of a childclass Python

Tags: python, oop, object, inheritance

I have this Button class derived from pygame.Rect:

```
class Button(pg.Rect):

    def __init__(self, left, top, width, height, char):
        super().__init__(left, top, width, height)
        self.char = char

    def draw_rect(window):
        pg.draw.rect(window, pg.Color("red"), "rectobject")
```

pg.draw.rect takes Rect object as a third argument. So I'm wondering if super() method instantiates the object of the parentclass and if so how to reference it (as we use self for class).
I know this is a trivial problem but I'm interested in how these things work in Python. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is only one object here, which is an instance of both the parent and child classes.  The `super().__init__()` call does the initialization (NOT instantiation) needed for the object to be a functional `Rect`, the rest of your `__init__()` does the initialization needed for the object to be a functional `Button`.

Comment: @jasonharper that explains it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inherited pg.rect, and you initialized your object like a pg.rect object. So your Button object have all attributes which are in the pg.rect objects. You can use a Button object in case where you can use pg.rect object. (Also you need to add self argument to `draw_rect` method)

```
import pygame as pg

display = pg.display.set_mode((100,100))

class Button(pg.Rect):

    def __init__(self, left, top, width, height, char):
        super().__init__(left, top, width, height)
        self.char = char

    def draw_rect(self, window):
        pg.draw.rect(window, pg.Color("red"), self)


b = Button(10,10,10,10,"a")

b.draw_rect(display)

pg.display.update()
```

And calling `super().__init__` not instantiates anything, it initialize your `self` parameter. So your `self` object will have attributes like `bottomleft` which are coming from `super().__init__`.

Comment: Wasn't sure if usage 'self' is proper because of 'char'. Now it's clear, and yes I missed the self argument. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, pg.draw.rect doesn't care about ``char`` attributes.

Comment: and sorry, but one more question. So this is general rule that redundant arguments are just ignored in cases like this?

Comment: Imagine that you wrote a class. This class have a method. For example, if you are trying to access ``self.char`` in this method, for sure you must have assigned a value to it. So yes, there is not a reason for not ignoring custom attributes. Because it don't need to access that attribute, nor change it.

Comment: as a beginer I must say that this kind of explanations are very helpful. Seems I got all the answers I wanted. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

A call to super() in a child class implicitly invokes the parent's constructor that causes the child object to have all the properties that a parent has and you can simply access them by using child.parentVar

There is a difference of syntax between python 2.x and 3.x

The syntax for invoking the parent's super and its semantics are discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33191175/12507046

Comment: I get in now, I use python3 but will look in this differences. Many thanks