# Adding method to inherited class in Python 3

Tags: python

I am pretty new in python and having a hard time with classes.

Here is the guide:

> - Add a Boss class which inherits all of the features of the Character class.
> - Add the following method to the Boss class: spawn(), generates a Minion named "Minion" with HP and attack equal to 1/4 (rounded down) of the Boss's max. The Minion should be the same level as the Boss but have 0 exp and 0 defense.

So how to generates a Minion named "Minion" with HP and attack equal to 1/4 (rounded down) of the Boss's max?

if I try this line of code, and give each of the variable its difference method,  in that case  where "spawn" method should go?

```
class Boss(Character):
    def __init__(self, name=Minion, lvl=1, hp=100, at=10, df=1, exp=None):
        self.name = name
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.hp = hp
        self.at = at
        self.df = df

    def spawn(self):
```

Comment: `return Character(name="minion", at=0,....)` that's all and it goes under `spawn`.  This creates a new character with the specified stats.  I don't know if you need a `Boss.__init__` and I **know** the Boss init shouldn't take Minion as a default name.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's true @JLPeyret as it seems like `Minion` is its own class. Can you share a stub of the Character class as well? Perhaps the Minion class too so folks know what the initialization will look like.

Comment: if what's true?

Comment: I believe Minion would be its own class (also a Character). It wouldn't make sense for a Boss to generate a raw Character object that it is inheriting from, makes more sense for Boss to generate a Minion object.

Comment: You should call `super().__init__(...)`

Comment: why do you need a Minion class?  does it have any characteristics or methods that are not described by its name, hp, at, df, attributes that are presumably present in the Character class?

Comment: thank guys! I think @JLPeyret is right

Answer (score 1):

The Guide says `Boss` is just like `Character` except for the addition of `spawn`, so you shouldn't be defining `__init__` (`Character` already has one) and should be writing the body of `spawn`.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for reaching out for help about this.
There are actually [quite](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) [a lot](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) of [tutorials](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_object_oriented_programming.php) on classes and how they work. I'd suggest finding a blog, book, or video and just work through it.

However for your particular issue I'd suggest setting up your minion as it's own class. Then setting up your boss with a spawn method that creates minions.
You'll need the [super constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/how-to-invoke-the-super-constructor-in-python) for this to work.

The idea behind this is that your class "hierarchy" will look like this:

```
         Object
           | 
        Character
        |
      Boss
```

What this shows us is that *all* of your classes will be children of `Object`. `Boss` is a child of `Character`. It is common to hear this relationship described as a "is a". i.e. Boss *is a* Character.

Moving forward.

Let's imagine your `character` class looks like this:

```
class Character(Object):
    def __init__(self, name="Placeholder",
                 level=1, hp=10, attack=10, 
                 defense=10, experience=0):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.experience = experience
```

Spawning a minion from you boss is rather simple. Try constructing a new character with the relevant stats. This might look something like the following:

```
class Boss(Character):
    '''
     Defines the boss class.
     Which by default has the following values:

       Name: "Boss"
       level: 100
       hp: 10000
       attack: 1000
       defense: 1000
       experience: 10000 
    '''
    def __init__(self, name="Boss", level=100,
                 hp=10000, attack=1000, defense=1000,
                 defense=1000, experience=10000):
        super(Boss, self).__init__(
            name=name, level=level,
            hp=hp, attack=attack,
            defense=defense, experience=experience
        )

    def spawn(self):
        '''
        Spawns a single minion
        '''
        return Character(name="Minion", level=self.level,
                         hp=round(self.hp / 4),
                         attack=round(self.attack / 4),
                         defense=0, experience=0)
```

There are tons of other ways to accomplish this using other paradigms, but this is a good starting point for OOP. If you'd like a little help with types and even spawning different kinds of minions I'd suggest [researching enums in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

EDIT: Example including `Minion` subclass

This would change your inheritance tree like so:

```
         Object
           | 
        Character
        |      |
      Boss    Minion
```

Which, again. Means both your `Boss` and `Minion` are children of `Character` and thus by extension are children of `Object`.
You can describe this as: "Boss and Minion *are* Characters".

Edited code below:

```
class Character(Object):
    def __init__(self, name="Placeholder",
                 level=1, hp=10, attack=10, 
                 defense=10, experience=0):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.experience = experience

class Minion(Character):
    '''
    TODO: define any special attributes,
          abilities, etc of the minion
    '''
    pass

class Boss(Character):
    '''
     Defines the boss class.
     Which by default has the following values:

       Name: "Boss"
       level: 100
       hp: 10000
       attack: 1000
       defense: 1000
       experience: 10000 
    '''
    def __init__(self, name="Boss", level=100,
                 hp=10000, attack=1000, defense=1000,
                 defense=1000, experience=10000):
        super(Boss, self).__init__(
            name=name, level=level,
            hp=hp, attack=attack,
            defense=defense, experience=experience
        )

    def spawn(self):
        '''
        Spawns a single minion
        '''
        return Minion(name="Minion", level=self.level,
                         hp=round(self.hp / 4),
                         attack=round(self.attack / 4),
                         defense=0, experience=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I appreciate it. Going back to out question , the thing is it doesn't finish with Boss class, but also has its different "Minion" class also inherits Character class.

Comment: whole assignment is pretty complicated, I'm trying to figure it out, thanks you all for your help

Comment: @MohammedAlimbetov I'm not understanding your first comment fully. Are you saying the assignment wants you to build out a Minion class and a Boss class?

Comment: @TaylorCochran Yes. so its different minion class which also needs to be created. Would you mind leave you contact method(email, facebook) so I can send you whole assignment, if you wanna take a look? I am really struggling with it

Comment: @MohammedAlimbetov if that's the case, you can just have `class Minion(Character): pass` and then `return Minion(...)` in `spawn`.  now you specifically get a Minion.

Comment: @MohammedAlimbetov I've edited the post with an example of JL's suggestion